# Animating Search Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [this](http://icanbecreative.com/article/css3-animated-search-box) to create an animated search box.

The only thing, is that I need the position to be `relative`.. I do not need need this in the middle of the screen, but rather under an `h2` element and have the same functionality.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkm91z7p/)

Here is the code:

**HTML**

---

```
<h2>
Testing Animated SearchBox
</h2>

<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="input-holder">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
        <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>
```

---

**JS**

---

```
searchToggle = function searchToggle(obj, evt){
    var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
        if(!container.hasClass('active')){
            container.addClass('active');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
            container.removeClass('active');
            // clear input
            container.find('.search-input').val('');
        }
}
```

---

**CSS**

---

```
h2{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.search-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {    
    height: 70px;
    width:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
    width:450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: black;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:'';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 9px;
    top: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    right:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
    right:-50px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FE5F55;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

---

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function searchToggle(obj, evt){
    var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
        if(!container.hasClass('active')){
            container.addClass('active');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
            container.removeClass('active');
            // clear input
            container.find('.search-input').val('');
        }
}
```

```css
.search-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {    
    height: 70px;
    width:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
    width:450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: #000;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:'';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 9px;
    top: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    left:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    /*transition-delay: -0.2s;*/
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
    left:475px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    /*transition-delay: 0.5s;*/
}
.search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FE5F55;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
Testing Animated SearchBox
</h2>

<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="input-holder">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
        <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>
```

You need remove `top` and `left` from search wrapper style

Check [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bkm91z7p/2/)

Comment: The position is absolute.. I need it to be relative

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change a little bit the positioning of the close element

```js
searchToggle = function searchToggle(obj, evt){
    var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
        if(!container.hasClass('active')){
            container.addClass('active');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
            container.removeClass('active');
            // clear input
            container.find('.search-input').val('');
        }
}
```

```css
h2{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.search-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {    
    height: 70px;
    width:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
  margin: auto;
    width:450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: black;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: black;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:'';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 9px;
    top: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    left: 50%;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
    left: calc(50% + 250px);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FE5F55;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
Testing Animated SearchBox
</h2>

<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="input-holder">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
        <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but for some reason in my own code, when I start typing in the textbox.. I get a white `x`, that shows up in the middle of the textbox and not on the right side.. and it doesn't show up in the sample you provided..

Comment: also my pointer is extemely glitchy when inside the searchbox as well.. appears, then disappears.. appears... then disappears

Comment: I fixed the first problem.. I had a `max-width` on text-areas...but when I click in the textbox. I can't see the blinking cursor

Comment: Second question.. is there a way to hide the `close` button until you click on the `search` button and then it appears like it does normally?

Comment: I have changed a little the colors. Now I think it's better.

Comment: You can link the appearance to the focus state of the input

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The changing of colors helped.. but one last thing.. when I click on the button (I would like it to be centered).. the textbox should also be centered on the page.. how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I have edited the snippet. Now the button is initially centered, and so the textbox.